# Does a union always have default value of zero?

Tags: c++

Please let us consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union{
 int i;
}u;

int main(){

     int k=5;
     cout<<k+u.i<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code  shows me output  5,what means to me is that,variable i in union structure  has default value=0, but  the same code   on ideone.com  shows warning like this

```
prog.cpp:6: warning: non-local variable ‘<anonymous union> u’ uses anonymous type and then prints  5 as well, and last one  core of this problem comes  from algorithm calculate
```

Reciprocal of the square root  and here is code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

float invsqrt(float x){

    float xhalf=0.5f*x;

    union{
         float x;
         int i;
    }u;

   u.x=x;
   u.i=0x5f3759df-(u.i>>1);
   x=u.x*(1.5f-xhalf*u.x*u.x);

   return x;
}

int main(){

    float  x=234;
    cout<<invsqrt(x)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It shows me output also,but my question  is that is it a this code good?i meant that because  int i is not initailized ,can any compiler consider it's value as zero?i  am curious  and please tell me something about this,also if something is not clear from my question  say me,i am not English native speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does a union always have default value of zero?

The language standard says this:

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>     and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>     rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

So, in your first code sample, `u.i` will be initialised to zero.

I'm not sure about the second code sample at all. I cannot see the point of the `union` there. I rather suspect that you meant to use a `struct` rather than a `union`. But note that the two code examples are very different because the `union` in this first has static storage duration and in the second the `union` has automatic storage duration. This results in completely different semantics for uninitialized variables.

Comment: The second sample is using the union to convert a `float` to its bit pattern. It's technically undefined behaviour, and also relies on various implementation-defined details, but this is probably the most portable way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**General note**: warning - you seem to be expecting that the int member somehow has the same size as the float member of the union. This might be true, but need not. You also seem to assume that your compiler uses a certain floating point representation. To my  knowledge, the compiler has no such obligation<sup>2</sup>

> warning: non-local variable ‘ u’ uses anonymous type

just means that you should not really be using anonymous union types for externally visible symbols. This is a warning that you'll see locally too, if you compiled with `-Wall` (all warning on).

> it shows me output also,but my question is that is it a this code good?i meant that because int i is not initailized ,can any compiler consider it's value as zero?

As far as I can see from the code shown, `u.i` is *NOT* uninitialized. It is initialized per the fact that you assigned `u.x`. This is the actual definition of a union: a union stores the member fields *at the same memory location*. This means, that even though `u.i` might (haven't checked) be auto-initialized at 0<sup>1</sup> then you'll have overwritten it by assigning to `u.x`

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> (unlikely, because how would the compiler choose whether to 0-initialize .i or .x?)</sub>

<sup>2</sup> though in practice most will use IEEE formats (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) due the fact that most processors support that natively

Answer (score 1):

This is initializing the union variable :

```
union{
  float x;
  int i;
}u;
u.x=x;
```

meaning both `x` and `i` in the union are initialized.