# Avoid calling constructor of member variable

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have the following C++-class:

```
// Header-File
class A
{
    public:
    A();

    private:
    B m_B;
    C m_C;
};

// cpp-File
A::A()
: m_B(1)
{
    m_B.doSomething();
    m_B.doMore();
    m_C = C(m_B.getSomeValue());
}
```

I now would like to **avoid** the `class A` to call **any** constructor of `C m_C`. Because on the last line in `A::A()`, I'm anyways going to initialize `m_C` myself because I need to prepare `m_B` first. I could provide an empty default constructor for `class B`. But that's not the idea.

I have already tried to add `m_C(NULL)` to the init-list of `A::A()`. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it said there was no constructor taking `NULL` as an argument.

So how can I have `m_C` left uninitialized? I know that with pointers, the `m_C(NULL)`-way works. And I don't want to allocate it dynamically using `new`.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: An evil way is to have a "char m_C_data[sizeof(C)]" as a member, and then do a placment new into it when initializing. This will avoid heap allocation, but you will have to cast it to the right type everytime you use it. Of course the complexity of type C has to be kept in mind (is a POD, has vftable, <more things I don't know about>..etc.)

Comment: Does class C have a default constructor, which does nothing ? Else write one more constructor, which takes NULL as an arguement and make it explicit to be safe and does nothing.

Comment: Until now, it doesn't. And even though I didn't want it to have a default constructor, it looks like I just have to change it to have one.

Comment: Sadly the accepted answer is incorrect. Don't forget to scroll down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask is forbidden - and correctly so. This ensures that every member is correctly initialized. Do not try to work around it - try to structure your classes that they work with it.

Idea:

- C has a constructor that does nothing
- C has an initialization method that makes the class usable
- C tracks whether it has been initialized correctly or not and returns appropriate errors if used without initialization.

Comment: Well... I partially disagree. In the constructor, I'm ensuring that every member is correctly initialized, too. If you have a pointer, it isn't initialized "correctly" either. But it looks like I gotta take another way. Thank you!

Comment: Okay. I think the only solution is to create an empty default-constructor. The rest of the solutions seem to be nice, but not fitting for my current problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Atmocreations: the pointer itself is initialized correctly - according to the pointers "default constructor". It is normally not meaningful - if you are lucky it's 0.

Answer (score 9):

How about using technique described in this QA?

[Prevent calls to default constructor for an array inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304629/prevent-calls-to-default-constructor-for-an-array-inside-class)

```
std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T[n]), alignof(T)>::type
```

---

Or, you also can consider using of `union`. AFAIK, [unions will be initialized only with first named member's constructor.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751242/does-a-union-always-have-default-value-of-zero)

For example,

```
union
{
   uint8_t _nothing = 0; 
   C c;
};
```

According to the standard mentioned in the QA, `c` will be zero-initialized, and its constructor will not be called.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You don't even need `_nothing`; a `union` of one element will do.

Comment: Since C++17 you can also use the more convenient [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) for this matter. It does **not** allocate the necessary memory dynamically and offers `#emplace()` for a later in-place construction and `#operator=()` for easy assignment.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a *good* way to achieve what you want. This must be a workaround:

```
// Header-File
class A
{
    public:
    A();

    private:
    B m_B;
    C m_C;
    static int prepareC(B& b);
};

// cpp-File
A::A()
: m_B(1)
, m_C(prepareC(m_B))
{
}

int A::prepareC(B& b)
{
    b.doSomething();
    b.doMore();
    return b.getSomeValue();
}
```

Please ensure that `m_B.doSomething()`, `m_B.doMore()` and `m_B.getSomeValue()` don't touch `m_C` (directly or indirectly).

---

As @Tobias correctly mentions, this solution depends on the order of initialization. You need to ensure that the definitions of `m_B` and `m_C` are in this order.

---

Updated the code according to @Loki's idea.

Comment: you must be aware that the behavior of this depends on the correct order of the definitions of m_B and m_C. It works as long as m_C is defined after m_B. Please comment as such. Otherwise I like this version.

Comment: +1: Though I would make prepareC() a static member and pass b as a parameter.

Comment: Looks like a possibility to me. Why do I have to ensure that `m_B`'s methods don't touch `m_C`?

Comment: @Atmocreations: Because this would be undefined behaviour: `m_C` is still not initialized!

Comment: @Atmocreations: Just don't pass m_C as a parameter to the constructor of m_B. And make sure m_C is declared after m_B in the class declaration.

Comment: @Loki: there is a slight possibility that `m_B`'s methods access the instance of `A` being constructed (for example: `A` passes `this` to `m_B`'s constructor). Therefore it's better to recheck. :) But for the normal cases your advice is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

All member variables are full constructed when the construcotr code block is entered. This means there constructors must be called.

But you can work around this restriction.

```
// Header-File
class A
{
    struct Initer
    {
         Initer(B& b)
             : m_b(b)
         {
             m_b.doSomething();
             m_b.doMore();
         }
         operator int()  // assuming getSomeValue() returns int.
         {
             return m_b.getSomeValue();
         }
         B& m_b;
    };
    public:
    A();

    private:   // order important.
    B m_B;
    C m_C;
};


// cpp-File
A::A()
: m_B(1)
, m_C(Initer(m_B))
{
}
```

Comment: Could you do something similar with a static `Init` method?  E.g. `m_B(1), m_C(Init(m_B))`.  I wanted to put that in my answer, but I wasn't sure if it was legal or not.

Comment: @merlyn-morgan-graham: Yes. You need to define a conversion operator that will convert an object of type Init into a type T (where T is the same as the result type as getSomeValue()).

Comment: I meant to define `Init` as: `private: static int Init(B& b) { /* init here */ return b.getSomeValue(); }`.  It seems your comment on the other answer might confirm that this works.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Yes using a private static method is cleaner than this. I would go with Vlad's idea now that I have seen it.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Thank you! I like this solution. Although I find it easier to just create an empty constructor for `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use comma expressions:

```
A::A()
  : m_B(1)
  , m_c((m_B.doSomething(), m_B.doMore(), m_B.getSomeValue()))
{
}
```

Obviously, as others have explained, `m_B` better be declared before `m_C` else `m_B.doSomething()` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Assuming C does not have a 3 parameter constructor.

Comment: In which case you add parantheses: `:m_c((foo(), bar(), baz()))`

Comment: thanks for your respone. the idea is nice and works well for few instructions. but considering the number of instructions i need to do before being able to instanciate `m_C`, thifs looks just plain ugly to me.

Comment: @Atmocreations: This is rather less ugly than adding dynamic allocation or invalid object states.  Factor it out if you like, or initialize `m_B` with a helper function that creates an object in the appropriate state (but it then must be movable).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allocate it dynamically using `new` for code clutter/exception safety reasons, you can use a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr` to solve this problem.

A solution that avoids `new` is to edit `C` to have a two-step initialization process.  The constructor would then construct a "zombie" object, and you'd have to call an `Initialize` method on that `m_C` instance to finish your initialization.  This is similar to the existing cases you found where you could pass `NULL` to the constructor, and later go back to initialize the object.

**Edit:**

I thought of this earlier (even though it looks much like other people's solutions).  But I had to get some confirmation that this wouldn't break before I added this solution - C++ can be quite tricky, and I don't use it very often :)

This is cleaner than my other suggestions, and doesn't require you to mess with any implementation but that of `A`.

Simply use a static method as the middle-man on your initialization:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();

private:
    static int InitFromB(B& b)
    {
        b.doSomething();
        b.doMore();
        return b.getSomeValue();
    }

    // m_B must be initialized before m_C
    B m_B;
    C m_C;
};

A::A()
    : m_B(1)
    , m_C(InitFromB(m_B))
{
}
```

Note that this means you can't allow `m_B` to depend on the instance of `A` or `C` at all, whereas the solutions at the top of this answer might allow you to pass `A` or `m_C` into `m_B`'s methods.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is storing pointers to a `B` and a `C`. These can be initialized to 0, omitting any construction. Be careful not to dereference a null pointer and delete it in the destructor of `A` (or use `std::unique_ptr`/`boost::scoped_ptr`).

But why not initialize `m_B` first (through a proper constructor call, not in `A::A()`, and then use that initialized `B` instance to initialize `m_C`? It will call for a small rewrite, but I bet it'll be worth the code cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer sounds like the only clean solution to me. The only other solution I see is to have a default constructor for C that does nothing and have an initialising method in C you call yourself later.

m_C.Initialise( m_B.getSomeValue() );

Answer (score 0):

Here we have the building blocks:

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
  C(int i){std::cout << "C::C(" << i << ")" << std::endl;}
};

class B
{
public:
  B(int i){std::cout << "B::B(" << i << ")" << std::endl;}
  void doSomething(){std::cout << "B::doSomething()" << std::endl;}
  void doMore(){std::cout << "B::doMore()" << std::endl;}
  int getSomeValue(){return 42;}
};
```

If you want to make a new kind of construction for B consider making a derived class:

```
class B1 : public B
{
public:
  B1() : B(1)
  {
    doSomething();
    doMore();
  }
};
```

Now use the class B1 that is derived from B:

```
class A
{
private:
  B1 _b;
  C _c;
public:
  A() : _c(_b.getSomeValue()){std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;}
};
```

And then:

```
int main()
{
  A a;
}
```

Output:

```
B::B(1)
B::doSomething()
B::doMore()
C::C(42)
A::A()
```