# How can I catch an exception throw from an object initialized with curly braces?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, constructor, try-catch

I'm confronted to a problem. I have this :

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        Class A obj;
    } 
    catch()
    {
     ...
    }
}

class B
{
    public:
        B(){throw an exception there from .cpp};
        ~B();
};

class A
{
    public:
        A();
        ~A();

     private:
        B objB{} // <=== Exception from there, how can I catch it ?
}
```

As you can see, I don't have any idea how can I get the exception when I initialize an object with curly braces from the header file.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This [live example](http://ideone.com/bzaIhM) demonstrates the technique of function-level `try` blocks.

```
A()
try {
   /* code */
} catch( exception e ) {
  throw e;
}
```

note, however, that you **must** throw an exception if the above construct catches something.  It need not be the same exception.  This is because the construction of `A` has failed (the exception has bypassed parts of the construction of `A`, and/or some subobject of `A` had its constructor terminated), and the only way to exit a constructor with a failed construction is via a `throw`.

Comment: Note that if you want to avoid this, you could wrap the `B` into the equivalent of a `std::optional` and defer construction until you are within code you control.  As a side effect, an `A` could either have a `B` or not, so you can have a valid `A` with a failed `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible as such. Indeed, it is very similar to [Avoid calling constructor of member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833904/avoid-calling-constructor-of-member-variable) and would leave the `objB` member of `A` not constructed. A solution is to split the constructor of `B` in two steps:

1. A default constructor that does nothing
2. A `initialize` method which trow the exception. You can pass the braces to that method.
3. `B` check that is is properly initialized before doing anything else.